# How to allow specific groups to post in specific categories on Joomla?

Tags: acl, joomla-user-groups

I've been looking for an answer to this problem, but the only thing I find are simple examples that can't solve my problem. I'm new to Joomla and I've tried to manage this as I used to do it in phpBB, where you had groups of users that could post in certain forums, and a user could be a part of one or more groups with different permissions. I wanna do the same here.

For example, I wanna have three groups of users; G1, G2, G3.

Also, I have two categories: Cat2, Cat3. G2 can post to Cat2 ONLY. G3 can post to Cat3 ONLY.

So, User1 belongs to G1, and he can't post anything, anywhere. He's just a registered user that can access certain areas.

User2 belongs to G2 and G3, so he can post in Cat2 cand Cat3.

User3 belongs to G2, so he can post only in Cat2, but not in Cat3.

How can I achieve this?
I even read something like there's not a straightforward solution to this, which seems very weird to me, since it's a basic functionality to many forums/CMS.

[tl;dr I wanna do the thing in this diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQfHN.jpg)

Comment: User permissions in Joomla are part of an ACL so you should be able to achieve any setup that any ACL system could achieve. The specific of how would depend on what forum system/component you're using. If you're developing your own forum component then it would be up to you to use the ACL as needed. If you're using a 3rd party system then it would depend on that systems capabilities.

Comment: ACLManager might be helpful for working this sort of thing out https://www.aclmanager.net/

Comment: This question has also been asked at: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46698548/1983389